# Can't Start Azure Emulator "Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057."

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-worker-roles

I have an Azure 2.8.1 project that "just works" on one machine, and on another completely fails to start -- I'm pulling my hair out trying to get this to work.

The project contains a worker role (2 instances) and a web role (1 instance).

The progress bar goes to about ~80% and then it fails -- if I switch over to the compute emulator, I just see errors about the services being unhealthy or busy.

In Visual Studio I eventually get the following error message:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

There was an error attaching the debugger to the role instance
'deployment28(5).MySolution.WebRoleProject_IN_0' with Process Id: '13288'.
Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057.

---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Any help troubleshooting this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was related to file pathing.  If there is any file or folder over 260 characters in length the project path, the Azure emulator  will completely crap out on you (even if it's not in source control, and it's not included in your project or package).

I hit this problem because NPM (prior to version 3.x) creates super deep folder structures under `node_modules` folders that it creates.

I got around the problem by deleting all of my node_modules folders, upgrading to NPM 3.5.2, and then re-running npm install.

Answer (score 1):

Run Visual Studio 2015 as administrator, there many related issues with compute emulators caused by unprivileged execution .

Comment: I was already running as an administrator. (I always do, because it solves a ton of random issues with Visual Studio.) -- Also, because it's a requirement to even run the Full Azure emulator (Visual Studio at least tells you about that though).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using the **express emulator** on the machine where you are not able to run the project. 
The express emulator does not emulate  multiple instances of your worker roles!

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was using the Full Emulator.  Running multiple instances of my worker roles is not related to this issue.  (Also, Visual Studio will just tell you that anyway, not give you a cryptic 0x800 error.)